# infopath > How to make sure there is an attachment

Tags: infopath, attachments, validation

Creating a resume upload form where user must upload attachment. On submit button I want to disable submit button if attachments is not present? I added Attachments is not present and this seems to be not working.

It looks like File attachment does not or can not have Rules.

I created a column "VerifyAttachment" a Boolean field. so I can update this field whether user added file or not. But not sure where I am going to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Its quite straight forward.

1. Select the submit button and add a validation rule, stating a condition that if "VerifyAttachment" is false then check the checkbox below to hide the control. This means that Submit button gets enabled only if the field "VerifyAttachment" is true. Make sure that the default value for this boolean field is false.
2. Now, add an Action rule selecting the attachment field, stating that if the attachment field "is present" then trigger an action -> Set a field's value, which would be the "VerifyAttachment" field, to true.

Thats it. This should work.

Comment: Action rule is not present for the Attachmend field.

Comment: Select the attachment field, click on manage rules, add a rule, on the new button you have a drop down to select action.

Comment: I created infopath form from sharepoint list and therefore it's brining it's own attachment control. i tried to add a attachments control from controls but is not even there.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the question is about the attachments to a custom list, the Formatting rule should analyze the condition 'my:Attachments is blank' the appropriate Action is up to the designer. No additional boolean fields are necessary IMHO.